# Aweber Regex Puzzle

Tags: regex, parsing, email, puzzle

I'm using Aweber's automatic email parsing for Unbounce form submissions and it seems that their default regex is a bit wonky:

They match email with `\nemail:\s+(.+?)\n` and name with `\nname:\s+(.+?)\n`

The problem is that because I'm not asking users for their name, their regex automatically grabs the next line, which is ===== FORM DATA =====, so it emails users with "Hi ===== FORM DATA =====!"

Here's what a sample Unbounce email looks like:

```
page_name:
page_id: 2b78ddde-e7bb-11e1-9fde-12313e00ec56
page_url: http://www1.sample.com
variant: C
email: sample@gmail.com
name:

===== FORM DATA =====

email: [&quot;sample@gmail.com&quot;]
ip_address: 88.253.**.**



--
The Unbounce Team
Toll Free 1-888-515-9161
support@unbounce.com
http://unbounce.com
```

How do I modify their regex so that it stops at the end of the line if there's no value present?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the name regex to the following:

```
\nname:[ \t]+(.+?)\n
```

The change here is to replace `\s` with `[ \t]`, because `\s` will match newlines.

This will cause the match to fail if a name is not provided, if you would like it to still match but put an empty string into the group, you can use the following:

```
\nname:[ \t]*(.*?)\n
```

As noted by Evandro Silva, you can make this regex more efficient by replacing the `.+?` or `.*?` with `[^\n]+` or `[^\n]*`, respectively.

Comment: remember that `.+?` is CPU expensive, use negated lists instead [^\n]

Comment: Good point, added that to the answer.  Whoever downvoted, care to explain?

Answer (score 0):

Try regex pattern `[\n\r]name:[^\S\n\r]*([^\n\r]*)`

Comment: This won't work on linux though... This one will: `\nname:[\s\t]*([^\n]+)`

Comment: @EvandroSilva - Why wouldn't it work? The ``\n\r`` isn't specifying a combination, only a negated character class. I think Omega's solution is fine...

Comment: @acheong87 Actually you're right, the `\n\r` is specified in a list, think I've done something wrong.